# Jetpack Compose unit testing performClick() not working with compose:1.1.0 update

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, testing, android-jetpack-compose

I have updated my project to kotlin:1.6.10 and compose:1.1.0 version. After updating the versions my unit test case is keep on loading at performClick() it's never getting completed

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.